# Run model method after user creates a object in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm looking for help with a problem I'm facing. I have a referral program and i would like to run a method when the user who was referred creates a `Post`. In my `user.rb` file I have:

```rb
def complete_referral!
  update(referral_completed_at: Time.zone.now)
end
```

And my `PostsController` has:

```rb
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
  @post.save
end
```

Some ideas I've tried was trying to run the complete_referral! method on `post.rb` like so:

`after_create :complete_referral!`

but that just raised an `undefined method complete_referral!' for #<Post:0x00007ff65b0514d8>` error.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You would do that in the post model rather than in the user model, so go to post.rb and add it to that file referring to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the callback in the `Post` class, e.g.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :complete_referral!
  # ...

  private
  def complete_referral!
    user.complete_referral!
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah, obviously. Thanks!

Comment: Is there also a way to use this in the PostsController, rather than in the model itself? Defining the complete_referral! as self.complete_referral! and creating the private method you posted in the PostsController yields in `undefined local variable or method user for  Did you mean? super`

Comment: Do you have a relation between `Post` and `User`? How is it called?

Answer (score 3):

You could also use an [association callback](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks):

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :referrer, class_name: 'User', optional: true
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :referred_posts, 
    class_name: 'Post', 
    foreign_key: 'referrer_id',
    after_add: :complete_referral!
end
```

The callback is then called when you create a post from the association:

```
@post = User.find(some_param).referred_posts.new(post_params)
```

The reason I would use this instead of a regular callback is that it does not create a hard dependency from Post to User that you have to address in all your tests when you just want to create a post record.

Comment: Thanks! It seem that i would like to use something like unless current_user with the after_create and unfortunately that doesn't quite work. How would you approach this, but instead of using the Post model using the PostsController?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. `@post = User.find(some_param).referred_posts.new(post_params)` is something you would do in your `PostsController#create method`. If you wanted to do this conditionally if there is a current user you can do `@post = current_user  ? current_user.referred_posts.new(post_params) : Post.new(post_params)`.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers use callbacks, and I love callbacks in my models, *if* the callbacks are necessary to keep my data in a correct state. In this case I would prefer to do this in the controller, because *only if* a post is saved through the controller (by a user), do we want to call `complete_referral!` *on the user*, not when we create a post in the tests or in the console (or on import etc.etc.)

So in that case in the `PostsController` we write

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
  if @post.save
    current_user.complete_referral! 
  end 
end
```

Comment: You kind of defeat the whole point of your argument by not checking the return value of save in the example.

Comment: Thank you this worked like a charm! Managed to add this to the controller and now it runs the complete_referral! only on user's that have been referred `current_user.complete_referral! unless (current_user && current_user.referred_by_id.nil?)`

Comment: @max definitely good point, of course I simply extended the OP's example, I am assuming they have error handling in their code as well (and simplified the code for this example --also a referral system is in general more complicated). But I edited the code accordingly.